# NLTK stemming does not pass a simple case

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spell-checking, stemming

I am new to NLTK, and I'm using stemmer function on stemming cases.

I have a simple example sentence to process, which is: "Turn on the lightin." I want to see if NLTK stemmer could help me filter out the typo "lightin". I've tested stemmer with "lighting", and snowBall stemmer can return the correct word "light" for me, but snowBall stemmer returns "lightin" in my test.

My stemming process is very trivial:

```
tokens = "Turn on the lightin"
for token in tokens:
    print("SnowBall Lemmatizer: "+snowBallStemmer.stem(token))
```

According to NTLK's doc, snowBallStemmer could be used to stem English. I want to know why snowBallStemmer failed to stem "lightin" and what could I do to fix this.

Comment: The Snowball stemmer is rule-based, so it should be straightforward to edit it. Have a look at the [source](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/stem/snowball.html#EnglishStemmer): you need to add 'in' to the list of step-1b suffices. (If you do this in a child class, it gets a bit tricky with the class attributes, though...)

Comment: @lenz This helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try running a spellchecker (e.g. [pyenchant](http://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/tutorial.html)) before stemming:

```
>>> import enchant
>>> from nltk.stem import SnowballStemmer

>>> d = enchant.Dict("en_US")
>>> d.suggest('lightin')
['lighting', 'lighten', 'light in', 'light-in', 'lightning', 'lightering', 'sighting', 'light', 'flitting', 'Litton']

>>> snowball = SnowballStemmer('english')
>>> snowball.stem(d.suggest('lightin')[0])
u'light'

>>> sent = "Turn on the lightin".split()
>>> [snowball.stem(word if d.check(word) else d.suggest(word)[0]) for word in sent]
[u'turn', 'on', u'the', u'light']
```

Comment: You can, but d.suggest('lightin') only works for this specific case when you manually pick the first suggestion.

Comment: I'm interested to see how many % accuracy this would achieve on your dataset. And if this is not enouvh. And whether smarter perplexity methods in selecting the suggestion helps.

Comment: Spellchecker has a pretty pure accuracy in my case.